# Docker container running nodemon "exited with code 0"

Tags: docker, docker-compose, nodemon

I run `docker-compose -f docker-compose-base.yml -f docker-compose-dev.yml up`

Which outputs:

```
...
api    |
api    | > api@0.0.0 start:development /usr/src/api
api    | > npm run start:dev
api    |
api    |
api    | > api@0.0.0 start:dev /usr/src/api
api    | > nodemon -L
api    |
api exited with code 0
```

When I go into the container and run /bin/bash using `docker-compose -f docker-compose-base.yml -f docker-compose-dev.yml run --rm api /bin/bash`, nodemon runs fine:

```
# npm run start:dev

> api@0.0.0 start:dev /usr/src/api
> nodemon -L

[nodemon] 1.18.10
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: /usr/src/api/src/**/*
[nodemon] starting `ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register src/main.ts`
```

Docker compose files:

```
$ cat docker-compose-base.yml docker-compose-dev.yml

version: "3"

services:
  api:
    build: .
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/api
      - /usr/src/api/node_modules
    env_file:
      - .env
    container_name: api
version: "3"

networks:
  # Use lb_lbnet network created by the load balancer repo (lb)
  # We do this because we need the load balance to resolve container names defined here to forward traffic
  default:
    external:
      name: lb_lbnet

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:11
    container_name: db
    restart: always
    env_file:
    - ./db.env # uses POSTGRES_DB and POSTGRES_PASSWORD to create a fresh db with a password when first run
    volumes:
      - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      # only used to upload DB dump:
      # - ./backup:/tmp/backup

  api:
    tty: true
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
```

Adding `tty: true` doesn't help.

**Update:** Here's the Dockerfile for api:

```
FROM node:11

WORKDIR /usr/src/api

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

# not using an execution list here so we get shell variable substitution
CMD npm run start:$NODE_ENV
```

Comment: what does docker-compose log say?

Comment: Also your docker compose doesnt have an image or build for your api service. Can we see the dockerfile for it? You likely don't have bash as your CMD or something

Comment: docker-compose logs aren't needed since I'm running `up` without `-d`. Just posted the Dockerfile.

Comment: Completely inexplicable. One of those gremlin cases. I ran `down` and `up` and cannot reproduce this issue any more.

Comment: I gave you an answer anyway, you likely changed something in your start:dev script which is why it's now working for you.

Answer (score 1):

Your npm executable 'start:dev' is either running as a background task, exiting immediately, or it runs then finishes and exits.

I'd recommend you change your dockerfile to have the following at the end instead of your current CMD line.

```
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT /entrypoint.sh "$NODE_ENV"
```

Now create a file called entrypoint.sh and put it in the same directory as your dockerfile. In your entrypoint.sh have the following.

```
#!/bin/bash
npm run start:$1 &
bash
```